# library not found for -lstdc++-static

Tags: c++, macos, installation, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to build wxFormBuilder_v3.5.0-beta-source. It comes with a shell file for creating the build files, but it keeps getting stuck with the following error:

```
==== Building Premake4 ====
Linking Premake4
ld: library not found for -lstdc++-static
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [bin/release/premake4] Error 1
make: *** [Premake4] Error 2
./create_build_files4.sh: line 91: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
./create_build_files4.sh: line 92: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
./create_build_files4.sh: line 93: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
./create_build_files4.sh: line 95: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4: No such file or directory
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.4 and yes I have XCode installed and have successfully built/installed C++ projects on this machine before.

I am aware that I must first install wxWidgets for this to work, and I have already successfully built/compiled/installed wxWidgets.

Here are lines 87-96 of the shell file (I prefixed the line numbers for your reference):

```
[87] # Build premake
[88] cd build
[89] make CONFIG=Release -C./premake/$platform
[90]
[91] ./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch codeblocks
[92] ./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch $rpath codelite
[93] ./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch $rpath gmake
[94] if [ "$platform" = "macosx" ]; then
[95]    ./premake/$platform/bin/release/premake4 --file=./premake/solution.lua $wxunicode $wxroot $wxversion $mediactrl $shared $arch xcode3
[96] fi
```

I'm not as worried about the file paths missing. I tried to run `make` directly from the correct directory and still got this error:

```
==== Building Premake4 ====
Linking Premake4
ld: library not found for -lstdc++-static
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [bin/release/premake4] Error 1
make: *** [Premake4] Error 2
```

What I'm primarily concerned with is finding the `-lstdc++-static` library and installing it, but I can't find it online. The only thing I can find related to it is to change settings in XCode when compiling iOS apps, which is not the case here. Any changes needing to be made will need to be made in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

That means that premake file path: ./premake/macosx/bin/release/premake4 does not exist. Please note that you are using relative path (starting from ./) and not the absolute one. Try to use absolute path and check the location of the premake4 executable.

ld: library not found for -lstdc++-static means that your linker cannot make the object using static linkage. Please check if you can build static binaries at all.

Create hello world test like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Try to build it

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test
```

and

```
clang++ -static test.cpp -o test
```

Results of such a test assure you that you able or not able to create binaries at all.

Comment: The path is incorrect to the files, but even correcting the path doesn't seem to fix it because the file it is looking for is nowhere to be found. If I go to the actual folder and run `make` directly, I still get `ld: library not found for -lstdc++-static` without the no such file/directory errors.

Comment: This is another error and related to the linker. Did you try "hello world " approach with static linking?

Comment: could you check, what exactly do you call: clang or clang++? If you call clang - try to replace it with clang++